# Compare two integer objects for equality regardless of type

Tags: c#, .net, math, boxing

I'm wondering how you could compare two boxed integers (either can be signed or unsigned) to each other for equality.

For instance, take a look at this scenario:

```
// case #1
object int1 = (int)50505;
object int2 = (int)50505;
bool success12 = int1.Equals(int2); // this is true. (pass)

// case #2
int int3 = (int)50505;
ushort int4 = (ushort)50505;
bool success34 = int3.Equals(int4); // this is also true. (pass)

// case #3
object int5 = (int)50505;
object int6 = (ushort)50505;
bool success56 = int5.Equals(int6); // this is false. (fail)
```

I'm stumped on how to reliably compare boxed integer types this way. I won't know what they are until runtime, and I can't just cast them both to `long`, because one could be a `ulong`. I also can't just convert them both to `ulong` because one could be negative.

The best idea I could come up with is to just trial-and-error-cast until I can find a common type or can rule out that they're not equal, which isn't an ideal solution.

Comment: `int3.Equals()` is not actually the overriden `Equals`, it's an overload (`Equals(int)` vs `Equals(object)`)

Comment: Do you mean "but case 3 fails"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does ((object)(int)1).Equals(((object)(ushort)1)) yield false?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25305393/why-does-objectint1-equalsobjectushort1-yield-false)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In case 2, you actually end up calling `int.Equals(int)`, because `ushort` is implicitly convertible to `int`. This overload resolution is performed at compile-time. It's not available in case 3 because the compiler only knows the type of `int5` and `int6` as `object`, so it calls `object.Equals(object)`... and it's natural that `object.Equals` will return `false` if the types of the two objects are different.

You *could* use dynamic typing to perform the same sort of overload resolution at execution time - but you'd still have a problem if you tried something like:

```
dynamic x = 10;
dynamic y = (long) 10;
Console.WriteLine(x.Equals(y)); // False
```

Here there's no overload that will handle `long`, so it will call the normal `object.Equals`.

One option is to convert the values to `decimal`:

```
object x = (int) 10;
object y = (long) 10;
decimal xd = Convert.ToDecimal(x);
decimal yd = Convert.ToDecimal(y);
Console.WriteLine(xd == yd);
```

This will handle comparing `ulong` with `long` as well.

I've chosen `decimal` as it can exactly represent every value of every primitive integer type.

Answer (score 0):

Integer is a [value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) type. When you compare two integers types, compiller checks their **values**.

Object is a [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx) type. When you compare two objects, compiller checks their **references**.

The interesting part is here:

```
 object int5 = (int)50505;
```

Compiller perfoms [boxing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/yz2be5wk(v=vs.110).aspx) operation, wraps value type into reference type, and `Equals` will compare references, not values.

Comment: It should be clear by the wording in the question that I know the difference between value and reference types, this doesn't answer the question at all, actually.