# C# object{int} not equal to object{int}

Tags: c#, object, types, datatable, dataview

I have a `DataTable` and I created a `DataView` from the `DataTable`. I grab a record from the `DataTable` (Let's say record 5). Then I sort the `DataView` and I am trying to find the **new index** of the record I grabbed prior to sorting the `DataView`.

So to find the location of the new record I will loop through each record and each item in the record until I find a record that has all matching items in the record.

My loop looks like this:

```
int currentRecord = 2;
DataRow tr = view.Table.Rows[currentRecord];

view.Sort = "Name ASC";

foreach (DataRowView drv in view)
{
    foreach(object itemA in tr.ItemArray)
    {
        foreach (object itemB in drv.Row.ItemArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} == {1}", itemA, itemB);
            if(itemA == itemB)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Match!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my output:
[image]
[image]

So as you can see here in the pictures it's returning true for `object{string}` but false for `object{int}` even when the values are the same.

What's going on here?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008317/compare-two-integer-objects-for-equality-regardless-of-type

Comment: If your value types are boxed compare them with `.Equals()` instead of `==`.

Comment: @JonathonChase that did the trick! Thanks! :)

Comment: @Auios It is actually possible to directly compare tr with drv.Row in your code to find the row. The DataView directly uses the DataRows from the DataTable, so comparing the referrences to DataRow works. This goes a lot faster than comparing the actual values in the row...

Comment: @NineBerry You're right. I am over complicating things. I've adjusted my code to tr.Equals(view[i].Row); now

Comment: It is actually better to use == instead of Equals() in this case because you actually want to compare the reference and not the content

Comment: As an additional proof of the problems of comparing boxed values, try this: `ReferenceEquals(10, 10)`, this will return `false` because the two `10`s are boxed independently and thus ends up as two distinct objects on the heap, both containing a boxed int.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Would it be faster to use ReferenceEquals or == then?

Comment: It doesn't matter, `ReferenceEquals` is *defined* as `objA == objB` and will usually be inlined if you actually manage to call it. However, a normal call to `ReferenceEquals` on two `object` variables will be compiled as a `ceq` instruction, exactly the same as `==` will, so they are in fact the same. Use whatever you feel is most appropriate for you and your team to understand what is going on. Personally I would use ReferenceEquals to make it 100% clear that we're dealing with the references and not the values, but again, it's the same either way.

Comment: Note that if you use the `==` operator and one of the operands is *not* an object, you might invoke something other than `ReferenceEquals` type of comparison though, which is why I prefer `ReferenceEquals` when I actually want reference comparison.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Thank you for the great tips! :)